# How to sync audio with kmsgrab video stream?

Tags: sync

I am trying to sync audio from the pulse stereo output with the video from kmsgrab. If I use the video stream as stream one the video is choppy. The command that works best a the moment is:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin \
    -avioflags +direct -fflags +igndts -fflags flush_packets -fflags discardcorrupt \
    -fflags nofillin -flags low_delay -fflags nobuffer -frame_drop_threshold 1.0 -async 0 \
    -f pulse  -thread_queue_size 256  -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor \
    -avioflags +direct -fflags +igndts -fflags flush_packets -fflags discardcorrupt \
    -fflags nofillin -flags low_delay -fflags nobuffer -frame_drop_threshold 1.0 -async 0 \
    -f kmsgrab -framerate 25 -thread_queue_size 512 -i - \
    -vf hwmap=derive_device=vaapi,scale_vaapi=w=1920:h=1080:format=nv12 -c:v h264_vaapi \
    -compression_level 1 -b:v 4M -profile:v 578 \
    -map 0:a -map 1:v \
    -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c:a aac -ab 96k -ar 48k -ac 2 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc \
    -f flv -listen 1 -rtmp_flush_interval 4 -rtmp_buffer 3000 -rtmp_live live \
    -rtmp_subscribe out rtmp://0.0.0.0:1935/live/out
```

The only problem is that the sound is retarded by about 3 seconds. Also the video stream is delayed by about 2 seconds, so the delay of the audio stream in absolute values is 5 or 6 seconds.